# How to make an Avermedia AverTV Volar Green HD work?

Tags: software-installation, tv-tuner, dvb-t

How can I get a driver to make my [Avermedia AverTV Volar Green HD](http://www.avermedia.eu/avertv/fr/product/ProductDetail.aspx?Id=465) work ?

[image]

---

Now solved. See below:

- [solution for latest Ubuntu releases (14.04, 13.10)](https://askubuntu.com/a/395893/32413)
- [solution for older Ubuntu release (12.04)](https://askubuntu.com/a/272408/32413)
- [to check that it has been well installed](https://askubuntu.com/a/395930/32413)

Comment: I know it's a long time on but did you ever get HD channels working?

Comment: @Oli, yes it works with HD channels on Kaffeine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution on Ubuntu 13.10 & 14.04

[*from this source*](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/AVerMedia), note that this solution is simpler than on 12.04

---

### 1. Download the firmware

```
$ cd /lib/firmware/
$ sudo wget http://xgazza.altervista.org/Linux/DVB/dvb-usb-af9035-01.fw
$ sudo wget http://xgazza.altervista.org/Linux/DVB/dvb-usb-af9035-02.fw
```

### 2. Install the needed application

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
$ sudo apt-get install  libproc-processtable-perl
```

### 3. Install the latest v4l-dvb

*from the wiki [How to Obtain, Build and Install V4L-DVB Device Drivers](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers):*

```
$ git clone --depth=1 git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git
$ cd media_build 
$ ./build
```

### 4. Reboot

```
$ sudo reboot
```

### 5. Check if device is properly installed

[see below](https://askubuntu.com/a/395930/32413)

Answer (score 2):

### Solution on Ubuntu 12.4 kernel 3.2

---

### 0. Check your kernel

```
$ uname -r
3.2.0-39-generic-pae
```

### 1. Plug in the USB TV Tuner

You can check that it is correctly plug in with `lsusb`

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 07ca:a835 AVerMedia Technologies, Inc.
```

### 2. Download the driver for [AF9035 dvb-t usb dongle (3.2.x kernel version)](https://github.com/xgazza/DVB-AF9035_kernel-3.2.0#readme)

Note that this driver should work with:
 - Avermedia AVerTV A835 HD (ID 07ca:b835)
 - Avermedia AVerTV A835 HD PRO (ID 07ca:a835)
 - Avermedia AverTV A835 Green HD (ID 07ca:a835)
 - TerraTec Cinergy T Stick (ID 0ccd:0093)
 - TerraTec Cinergy T Stick 2 (ID 0ccd:00aa)
 - Avermedia AverTV A825 (ID 07ca:0825)

```
$ git clone git://github.com/xgazza/DVB-AF9035_kernel-3.2.0.git
$ cd DVB-AF9035_kernel-3.2.0
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

### 3. Download the firmware(s)

```
$ cd /lib/firmware/
$ sudo wget http://xgazza.altervista.org/Linux/DVB/dvb-usb-af9035-01.fw
$ sudo wget http://xgazza.altervista.org/Linux/DVB/dvb-usb-af9035-02.fw
```

I downloaded these 2 firmwares, I do not know which one is used.

### 4. Reboot

```
$ sudo reboot
```

### 5. Check if device is properly loaded

[see below](https://askubuntu.com/a/395930/32413)

Comment: In step 2 I used `sudo checkinstall` however installation of Debian package fails due an already present package (please find log message here: http://pastebin.com/w4AKVwcr).
Is it possible to exclude offending package or shall I just wait for a repo update? :(

Comment: … or just moving on could work: I didn't skipped step 2 but got the error as stated above. Anyway I followed along with downloading firmware and rebooting ~>  Everything works fine \^^/
Thank you very much for the detailed guide! <3

Comment: @yoshi with last kernel of Ubuntu 12.04, it is probably not needed anymore to perform step 2 (I did not check I use now Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 0):

### 5. Check if device is properly installed

```
$ ls /dev/dvb
adapter0
```

If this command returns something like `adapter0` => good
If it returns nothing => not good

### 6. Check with your TV application if the USB TV Tuner is recognized

I personally use [Kaffeine [image: Install kaffeine]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kaffeine). 
In tab `Television` | `Configure TV`, I get a new tab called `Peripherique 1`.

[image]
Note that for French TV, it is necessary to set the source with a shift of **167khz**.

Answer (score 0):

This process no longer makes the Volar Green functional in Ubuntu 14.04. The firmware has been re-mapped to dvb-usb-it9135-02 firmware instead of the dvb-usb-af9035 firmware which has completely broken my 4 tuner system. Used to work with 14.04 doesn't now.

I think the dvb-usb-it9135 is the correct firmware for the Volar Black and it has been assumed that it is also correct for the Volar Green.

The Green and the Black are different chips - simples!!!! ask any meerkat.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this? I keep getting the device show up using the dvb-usb-it9135-02 driver and tvheadend doesnt detect any services.