# Aver media A850 under ubuntu 14

Tags: dvb

I am familiar with the gui interface but am a reluctant user of terminal for lots of reasons.
I can see my device listed when I run `lsusb`, but when I run `dmesg` I get loads of pages of stuff and can't see my device. The following I have cut and pasted from linuxhardware:

The DVB-T USB stick AverMedia AVerTV Volar Black HD A850 has the USB ID `07ca:850a`:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 07ca:850a AVerMedia Technologies, Inc
```

The stick is supported under Linux since at least the kernel version 2.6.28 (Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic) by the kernel module `dvb_usb_af9015`.

A firmware file has to be installed to operate the the. This firmware file is part of the Ubuntu package `linux-firmware-nonfree`:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

The module loads automatically if the stick is plugged in:

```
$ dmesg
dvb-usb: found a 'AverMedia AVerTV Volar Black HD (A850)' in warm state.
dvb-usb: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer.
DVB: registering new adapter (AverMedia AVerTV Volar Black HD (A850))
af9013: firmware version:4.65.0
DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Afatech AF9013 DVB-T)
```

I have found the `dvb-usbaf9015.fw` firmware but it says it is a bin file and when I look up how to install bin files the nearest is installing ivtv which is not what I want.  I think I am very close but just need some advice as to how to load the `*.fw` file.

Comment: See in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/395893/32413) the way to install a similar AverMedia Tuner

Answer (score 0):

From [linuxtv.org](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-T_USB_Devices) this Usb DVB-T card should be supported.
So I think that you just need to copy your `dvb-usbaf9015.fw` in `/lib/firmware/`

```
cp dvb-usbaf9015.fw /lib/firmware/
```

Then **reboot** and check that your device is well installed:

```
ls /dev/dvb
adapter0
```

If this command returns something like `adapter0` => good
If it returns nothing => not good

So if it is "good", use your TV application to see if the USB TV Tuner is recognized:

I personally use [Kaffeine [image: Install kaffeine]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kaffeine). 
In tab `Television` | `Configure TV`, I get a new tab called `Peripherique 1`.

[image]
Note that for French TV, it is necessary to set the source with a shift of **167khz**.