# Kaffeine - channel scanning help

Tags: usb, tv-tuner, dvb-t

I'm trying to get Kaffeine to do a channel scan and am getting the "No available device found" alert. I previously did have Kaffeine working nicely (using this setup: [How to make an Avermedia AverTV Volar Green HD work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272407/how-to-make-an-avermedia-avertv-volar-green-hd-work) ) with all Australian channels until they changed the digital TV frequencies a couple of months ago.

I'm using the AVerTV Volar Green HD USB on Ubuntu 14.04, and in Kaffeine -> Configure Television it is recognised as Device 1, but when I try to do a channel scan it gives me the "No available device found".

Can anyone give me some assistance with this?

Problem solved with driver update and VLC media player.