# How to make an Avermedia AverTV Volar Green HD work on 16.04?

Tags: dvb-t

I have followed all steps in [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272407/how-to-make-an-avermedia-avertv-volar-green-hd-work/932535#932535), but it's not working for me on 16.04.

This is what I got:

```
marcecastro@marcecastro-VirtualBox:~$ uname -r
4.8.0-58-generic

marcecastro@marcecastro-VirtualBox:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 07ca:3835 AVerMedia Technologies, Inc. AVerTV Volar Green HD (A835B)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

marcecastro@marcecastro-VirtualBox:~$ dmesg | grep -i dvb
[ 2242.906283] dvb_usb_af9035 1-2:1.0: prechip_version=83 chip_version=02 chip_type=9135
[ 2242.921108] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: found a 'Avermedia A835B(3835)' in warm state
[ 2242.936232] dvb_usb_af9035 1-2:1.0: [0] overriding tuner from 38 to 60
[ 2242.981854] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: will use the device's hardware PID filter (table count: 32)
[ 2242.981905] DVB: registering new adapter (Avermedia A835B(3835))
[ 2243.015042] usb 1-2: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Afatech AF9033 (DVB-T))...
[ 2243.759518] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: schedule remote query interval to 500 msecs
[ 2243.759526] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: 'Avermedia A835B(3835)' successfully initialized and connected
[ 2243.759583] usbcore: registered new interface driver dvb_usb_af9035
[ 2245.087333] usb 1-2: DVB: adapter 0 frontend 0 frequency 0 out of range (174000000..862000000)
[ 8765.594031] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: usb_bulk_msg() failed=-110
[ 8765.594074] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: pid_filter() failed=-121
[16277.164754] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: 2nd usb_bulk_msg() failed=-110
[48628.199942] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: usb_bulk_msg() failed=-62
[48628.199954] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: rc.query() failed=-62
[48629.666347] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: usb_bulk_msg() failed=-62
[48630.697213] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: usb_bulk_msg() failed=-19
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: SOLVED: The USB tuner didn't get enough power from the USB HUB I was using. So, I plugged it in to the USB port, directly, and it worked!