# USB Capture device is "not an MTP device"

Tags: 18.04, usb

I am trying to connect my USB capture card to an Ubuntu 18.04 host.

When I'm connecting it, however, it connects and disconnects repeatedly. 
Syslog states it is "not an MTP device":

```
Jul 10 17:39:18 james-pc kernel: usb 1-10: new high-speed USB device number 114 using xhci_hcd
Jul 10 17:39:18 james-pc kernel: usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=07ca, idProduct=c835, bcdDevice= 0.00
Jul 10 17:39:18 james-pc kernel: usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul 10 17:39:18 james-pc kernel: usb 1-10: Product: Aver_C835_USB
Jul 10 17:39:18 james-pc kernel: usb 1-10: Manufacturer: AVerMedia Tech. Inc.
Jul 10 17:39:18 james-pc kernel: usb 1-10: SerialNumber: 202786700314
Jul 10 17:39:18 james-pc mtp-probe[11144]: checking bus 1, device 114: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10"
Jul 10 17:39:18 james-pc mtp-probe[11144]: bus: 1, device: 114 was not an MTP device
Jul 10 17:39:18 james-pc upowerd[6997]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10
Jul 10 17:39:24 james-pc kernel: usb 1-10: USB disconnect, device number 114
Jul 10 17:39:24 james-pc upowerd[6997]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10
```

How do I make Ubuntu recognize it as a USB capture device?

EDIT: No, this is not a duplicate of [How to make an Avermedia AverTV Volar Green HD work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272407). AverTV is an entirely different product, only produced by the same company. I am using an AverCapture HD GL310 card.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an Avermedia AverTV Volar Green HD work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272407/how-to-make-an-avermedia-avertv-volar-green-hd-work) Also check Additional Drivers. The proprietary drivers might be listed there but not installed.

Comment: No, "How to make an Avermedia AverTV Volar Green HD work?" does not seem to be a duplicate. It does not refer to MTP devices at all.

Comment: The chipset is the same therefore the drivers/firmware required is the same.